# How to change background color of GridToolbarColumnsButton overlay in x-data-grid version 6.xx

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am using MUI x-data-grid version 6.xx, and wanted to add dark theme to "CustomToolbar" overlay.

[overlay toolBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcfSQ.png)
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5juE.png)

Is there any way to add Dark background  and colorful font to these toolBar overlays for x-data-grid version 6.xx